# Obtaining and storing a Firestore instance in a long running service

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a static utility class which makes use of Firestore. The database operations are invoked occasionally by a background service. I expect this service to run for months on the user's phone.

I've been initializing an instance of Firestore in a static variable and using that throughout. Are there any bad effects of keeping an instance alive this way?

Is it better to call getInstance every time I need it? It seems like Firestore caches the result of getInstance.

```java
class FSWrapper {

   private static FirebaseFirestore fs = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

   public static operation1() {
       // do some reads
   }

   public static operation2() {
       // do some writes
   }
}


class BackgroundService extends Service {
    public void onSomeEvent() {
        FSWrapper.operation1();
        FSWrapper.operation2();
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` returns a singleton object, the same object every time.  It's never going to get garbage collected, so you can hold it for as long as you want anywhere you want with no downside (other than not being able to unit test with it correctly - you would want to inject the singleton some other way to do that).

Comment: So there's no uneccessary http/socket connection being kept alive this way? Is that connection created when getInstance is created the first time?

Comment: The SDK manages the connection internally.  You have no control over when it comes and goes.  It's not tied to the lifetime of the singleton.

Comment: If you need to know how it works internally, you are free to examine the source code.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-firestore